# Enforcing object keys from in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have

```
type Panel = 'store' | 'logs'
```

I want to create an object that has `key => ReactChild` with `key` being only the values in `Panel`

```
const object = {
    store: StoreComponent,
    logs: LogsComponent
}
```

How do I define the type of `object` here?

Comment: `const object: { [k in Panel]: ReactChild } = {...}`

Comment: @p.s.w.g `Record<Panel, ReactChild>` is shorter, but same idea, mapped type :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I like your solution the most; can you post it so I can mark it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predefined mapped type `Record` is what you are looking for. This will take a union of keys and create an object type where each property has the type specified as the second parameter to the type:

```
type Panel = 'store' | 'logs'

const object:Record<Panel, ReactChild> = {
    store: StoreComponent,
    logs: LogsComponent
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A combination of enum and types to restrict the keys would work:

```
enum Panel {
    store,
    logs
}

type MyObject = Partial<{ [ key in keyof typeof Panel ]: ReactChild }>

const object1: MyObject = {
    store: 2 // works
} 

const object2: MyObject = {
    whatever: 1 // invalid key
}
```

In my example, `ReactChild` is equal to `any` just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty clever to use Partial like that. 

I think this is equivalent and a little more straightforward 

`type MyObject = Partial<{ [ key in Panel ]: ReactChild }>`

Answer (score 2):

I think an enum would do what you're asking for:

```
enum Panel {
  Store = 'store',
  Logs = 'logs',
};

...

const object = {
  [Panel.Store]: StoreComponent,
  [Panel.Logs]: LogsComponent,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that provides reusable typing might be to define a "key to type" relation, and then construct a union type `PaneMap` that describes the value type per key in `Panel`:

```
type Panel = "store" | "logs"

/*
Define reusable type relation
*/
type PanelRelation<K extends  Panel, V>  = { [key in K] : V }

/* 
Define union type describing relation of keys from Panel, to specific value types. 
This ensures that specific keys are mapped to and compatible with specific value 
types 
*/
type PanelMap = 
PanelRelation<'store', StoreComponent> & 
PanelRelation<'logs', LogsComponent>


/* Usage example */
type LogsComponent = string
type StoreComponent = number


const object:PanelMap = { 
  "store": 1,
  "logs": "x",
  // "logs": 1, <-- value type mismatch produces expected error
  // "foo": 1, <-- foo key type not in Panel produces expected error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the type of `object`, you can use the `satisfies` operator (Typescript 4.9+).

```
type Panel = 'store' | 'logs'

const object = {
    store: StoreComponent,
    logs: LogsComponent
} as const satisfies Record<Panel, ReactChild>;
```

`object['store']`'s type would be the type of `StoreComponent`.